# Change script injection order for styled-components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm using styled-components in my reactjs app and I'm on a very frustrating situation, where my component defined styles get overridden by my global styles (that I import in the index.js file). I can solve this issue by using !important in those rules, but this is very far from ideal.

So, how can I make the styled-component script to inject the style dynamic tags AFTER the global injections? Is this configurable?